# Problems with less variables in _theme.less

Tags: magento2, compiler, less, setup-di-compile

I use below media queries in my custom _theme.less like

```
& when (@media-common = true) { }
```

but when I execute this command `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` I get variable `@media-common is undefined in file` what is wrong in this case?
Using grunt compiles without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fefe The `@media-common` variable is initially set in either:

- `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less`
- `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less`

This is *if* you're using either the blank or luma theme as a parent. If so, then this applies to you. If not, then whatever your parent theme is, should have a declaration and initialization of this variable...or if the parent theme you're using calls another for it's parent, the same applies.

Take a look at the `styles-m.less` and `styles-l.less` files to see the order in which less files are imported. You can also add some form of logging at `\Less_Parser::parseFile()`.

The way that I've gotten around this is to use a Less reference import [Less Docs: reference import option][1], which will *not* pull in the code within said Less file, it will just make the files available within the scope of the file requesting the import.

An example of what I've imported at the top of a custom Less file:

`@import (reference) "../source/lib/variables/_responsive.less"; @import (reference) "../source/lib/_responsive.less";`

*Note the path I'm using here in relative to my custom theme's custom Less file path in relation to the eventual `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/` path.

My custom theme directory hierarchy looks like this: `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/custom/custom.less`.

The files that I want to import are here:

- `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/source/lib/_responsive.less`
- `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/source/lib/variables/_responsive.less`

My custom file, which will be doing the import, will eventually live here:

- `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/custom/custom.less`

Now, with all of that said here's the kicker, you don't really need to do this. Why? Well, aren't the css styles within the [CSS Guards][2], in this case `@media-common = true` only meant to be called with the `styles-m.less` file? Yes, because M2 is supposed to be mobile first and therefore the `styles-m.less` file is the only file (save some email Less files and I think a few others) that actually has `@media-common` set to `true` (and there are only handful of files that even set this variable, period).

So anything that is within a CSS Guard which has the condition of `@media-common = true` is meant to be ran always, except for when the `styles-l.less` file is called. `styles-l.less` sets `@media-common` to `false` as the `styles-m.less` file should have already loaded up these 'common' styles...and if you look in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` you'll see that `styles-m.css` (which gets generated from `styles-m.less` if it isn't already generated [Dev Docs: .css request to .less search][3] - [More][4]  [Here][5]) gets loaded before `styles-l.css`.

This means that you could literally get around that error by defining `@media-common: true;` at the top of your custom Less file and based on what I've described above and what I'm understanding of the code so far, that should take care of the error.

**Here's the problem:** Whether you're including the `source/lib/_responsive.less` & `source/lib/variables/_responsive.less` files or defining your own `@media-common: true;` at the top of your custom file, this will overwrite the `@media-common: false;` assignment in `styles-l.less`, so you're going to get code duplication in both `styles-m.less` and `styles-l.less`. I don't see any way around that at the moment. The root issue of this is that our custom Less files aren't being loaded **after** both `styles-m.less` and `styles-l.less` or that the `@media-common` variable's value isn't being brought into the scope of our custom Less files. This shouldn't be the case, if we're importing our custom less via the `_extend.less` file, which the docs (suggest), as you have the following at the end of both `styles-m.less` and `styles-l.less`:

```
//@magento_import 'source/_extend.less';
```

I hope this has given you both insight and an immediate solution to your problem.

If you or anyone else comes up with a better solution, I'm all ears.

**UPDATE** So disregard what I mentioned above regarding code duplication. In my case I was both adding an explicit inclusion of my custom css in a page *and* I also added my custom less file to my theme's `_extend.less`.

I was modifying `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml` to include the following:

```
    <head>
        <!-- ADD PAGE-SPECIFIC STYLES SHEETS HERE -->
        <css src="css/pages/homepage.css" />
    </head>
```

and I also had an entry in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/source/_extend.less` of:

`@import "../pages/homepage.less";`

What I've found is that it's either or, not both. So in this case when M2 was trying to process a request for `http://vappey.dev/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/pages/homepage.css` it would load up the appropriate `homepage.less` file and this file wouldn't have `@media-common` within it's scope, so the error was telling. In order to get around that, add import references as I've mentioned above and they won't be any code duplication. Furthermore, but removing the entry from `_extend.less` my `styles-m.less` and `styles-l.less` won't look for the `homepage.less` file and there's no code duplication.

- My example here is for homepage-specific styles...but this illustrates a situation where I wasn't using the system correctly and that's why I was getting that error. I hope this helps
  [1]: https://lesscss.org/features/#import-atrules-feature-reference
  [2]: http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature
  [3]: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#server-side
  [4]: http://alanstorm.com/magento-2-frontend-files-serving/
  [5]: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_less_css/

Comment: worked to clean up this issue for me, great info!

Answer (score 2):

Old question I know but I ran into the same issue recently and found that the naming convention for your .less file can be cause.
When adding a custom .less file to your theme if you get the error `@media-common is undefined in file` update the .less file to prepend '_'.

In your example update file: custom _theme.less to _custom _theme.less
This changes how Magento 2 handles the LESS file when compiling.

Comment: You save my day!

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks, man.