# static-content deploy error

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.0, deploy, static-content

running static-content:deploy on multi store-view, fails with following error `variable @media-common is undefined` on theme where the language en_US

Comment: have you working on developermode or production mode?

Comment: locally on development

Comment: have you set client side development inside store configuration?

Comment: Go to that file and on that line number change `@media-common` to `@_media-common`

Comment: @Asish Hira 5 hm interesting `@_media-common` seems to work can u explain why?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @AsishHira Where is this answer of yours you are referring to? I am curious to know more about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@deroccha, I have laid out an answer to this question over here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152944/1956.

The long and short of it, is that `@media-common` isn't within the scope of your theme, in one or more .less files. We're supposed to be able to control this via use of [_extend.less](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#simple_extend) (which would load our custom files after `var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css/source/lib/_responsive.less`, but for some reason that doesn't always seem to work. That being the case, you can follow the instructions in the above link as a temporary solution.

**UPDATE** The use of `_extend.less` does work as long as there isn't another configuration somewhere, like adding an implicit css call on a page configuration xml file. An example implicit css call:

`<head>
    <css src="css/custom/theme.css" />
</head>`

If there is this type of entry, then there shouldn't also be an `@import` in the theme's `_extend.less` ...either or should be used.

Comment: Can you answer this question, please? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290595/variable-button-shadow-active-is-undefined-while-running-deploy-static-content

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was caused by first letter in my custom styles file name. File name should start from underscore, it provides proper files merging queue.
For instance,file with name product.less

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/theme/product.less
```

caused error during static content deploy @media-common is undefined.
Adding the underscore at the beginning of name resolved issue.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/theme/_product.less
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the same problem all day and I thought I'd lose my mind because everything was correct. Adding an undercore to my custom less file names solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

We found that deploying Magento 2 causes so much problems we just run in developer mode on the production site. Not a pretty solution but at least we can actually put sites live without a hundred errors.

Until the errors and the process is resolved by the core team we'll be using this solution. The github issue is more than a year old now. There is not even an official guide for deployment:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_deploy.html

Comment: Running in developer mode vs production mode doesn't solve the issue of the @media-common variable not being within the scope of Less files being transpiled. I do feel your pain though.