# Variable @button__shadow-active is undefined while running deploy static content in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, less, static-content-deploy, undefined-variable

I am getting this error whenever running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.

It showing variable @button__shadow-active is undefined in file en_US/css/source/_extends.less in _extends.less. How to solve this. Kindly help me.

Comment: can you please refer this doc. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#simple_override

Comment: you can copy the   -extends.less in  parent theme

Comment: Superb @divyasekar . It worked like a charm. Thank you. Just post your comment as an answer. I will choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple ways to customize a theme's styles

Refer [this document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#simple_override)

Copy your `_extends.less` in  parent theme to avoid undefined error