# Magento 2 - Importing LESS mixins/variables from lib

Tags: magento2, less, less-import

### Explanation

I'm really not a fan of loading all the CSS on every page regardless of whether it's required, to me this is bad practice. Therefore I am creating CSS files for certain areas, e.g homepage.css, account.css, product-page.css.

My problem is I now need to import Magento 2's variables and mixins, especially the media queries and `media-common` variables.

#### My Code

I have tried adding the below code to my LESS file but it returns an error, I have also tried reverse paths (../) but this didn't work and apparently is forbidden for security reasons (read in the Magento2 repo).

This is `app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Cms/web/css/homepage.less`.

```
// As this file is not imported we need to import the variables/mixins etc.

@import 'source/lib/_responsive.less';

@media-target: 'mobile'; // Sets target device for this file
@media-common: true; // Sets not to output common styles

@import 'source/_theme.less';

// My custom less being imported
@import 'layout/homepage/_homepage-carousel.less';
@import 'layout/homepage/_homepage-themes.less';
```

This still returns the error:

```
NameError: variable @media-common is undefined
in _homepage-carousel.less on line 4, column 9:

//  _____________________________________________
& when (@media-common = true) {
```

Yet the same code works in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less` despite the lib not being in the same directory.

### Question

**How can I import the mixins/variables from lib into my own custom CSS file?**

Comment: how are you creating less files that only load on specific pages? i know this isn't the question you are asking, but if you could point me to how to set this up, i'm curious how you get this working, even if the variable imports aren't working they way you want them to.

Comment: You can do this with Layout XML. So say you wanted a checkout CSS file you could add `<css src="Magento_Checkout::css/checkout.css" />` to `checkout_index_index.xml`

Comment: yes, but in the question you were asking about using less. Since everything i'm doing is in less, does magento convert that call to the `checkout.css` to a less file in the same location in the theme? and if so, how do you use grunt to compile that? After reading the question i was racking my head to how that would work, and couldn't find any info on setting that up.

Comment: I've never done this but I think you'd just need to add `Magento_Checkout::css/checkout.css` to your theme in `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`. If that doesn't work try moving the file to the theme module and then leave out `Magento_Checkout::`

Comment: @BenCrook have you found any solution to implement area wise less file implementation. Actually, I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No sorry, I very rarely work with LESS now so it's no longer a problem. We completely scrapped using the default workflow as it was so slow and overly complex.

Answer (score 2):

@Ben You can just add a reference import (as @mrtuvn mentioned above), except your path can be to `source/lib/_responsive.less` in your custom file...this needs to be relative to your theme's `web/css/` directory....as, once your files make their way down to:

```
var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/css
```

There will be the entire `lib/web/css` contents copied here already...

So in your custom theme:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/custom/custom.less
```

You'd add `@import` (reference) `../source/lib/_responsive.less` and that'll do it. If your editor/IDE has a LESS plugin for syntax highlighting (like PhpStorm) it will complain about not being able to find the `_responsive.less` file at that path, but ignore it...since the contents of `lib/web/css` and your custom theme's css get copied over to the same structure under `var/view_preprocessed`.

**UDPATE:** Here's a link to my answer for this question elsewhere, I provide a lot more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152944/1956

**UPDATE 2:** Here's a link to the Magento UI Library Docs which give a reference to this relative import path for UI Library contents: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/lib.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy essential files inside these folder to your folder theme

> lib/web/css/source/lib
>
> lib/web/css/source/components

Example you have homepage.less, account.less, product-page.less below `yourtheme/web/css`

you can import file by edit `your_theme\web\css\source\_variables.less` and add this line below to apply your custom style

```
@import '../homepage.less';
```

**UPDATE**
You can import source files by this way

```
@baseDirToLib: "../../../../../../../lib";
//@import 'source/lib/_responsive.less'; ORIGINAL WAY
@import (reference) '@{baseDirToLib}/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less';
```

Clear browser cache and refresh to apply new changed

Comment: So the only way is to duplicate the lib? That doesn't sound like best practice :( I will give it a try though, thanks.

Comment: Update my answer, give it a try. Hope it help you

Comment: I've tried this and similar methods and unfortunately it doesn't work, when I try and import a less file by going back some directories and I clear pub/static (and clear caches) my styles-m and styles-l CSS files do not get processed. If I remove the import they will then be processed again so it must be the imports that are breaking the Less pre-processing. Have you managed to get your example working?

Comment: @Ben-Space48 Did you manage to do this without duplicating the lib files? I have a similar situation with a custom theme (without a parent) that i want to import the lib less files when needed.

Comment: @David i think is there only way duplicate lib less files in your theme. You can't import external lib outside theme directory

Comment: @David - Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your custom less file:

```
//@magento_import 'source/lib/variables/_responsive.less';
```

Documentation about it: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#fedg_css-magento-import

Hope this helps.